Why Pauli exclusion principle and not Pauli exclusion law?
Why is the Pauli exclusion principle called a principle and not a law?

This belongs on HSM.

@Ghoster How to shift it?

@Ghoster I disagree. The difference between a law and a principle has to do with the meaning of words used in current Physics and not with its history.

See this question and note the variety in the answers. I’m with David Z who wrote “There is no consistent usage of these words among scientists.” Certainly no distinction between them was ever drawn in my physics education — whether high school, undergraduate, graduate, or postgraduate — in the U.S. Things may be quite different in other countries.

@Ghoster, I partially agree with David Z's answer. Certainly, there is no standardization in the language of Physics, although IUPAP is supposed to take care of it. However, this is a general statement. In the specific case of law and principles, there is a wide variety of examples that allow one to extract a general rule.

Although there is no standardization in the language used in Physics, the established usage of the words makes a difference between law and principle. The former is equivalent to a statement describing the behavior of a physical system under controlled circumstances. The latter is a law that is deemed to be foundational for a sector of Physics. A law may also correspond to an implicit definition of a physical concept when used as a principle.
Consequently, a statement about the behavior of Nature (a law) may be considered a principle in some formulation of the theory and not in another.
The so-called Pauli principle originates from old Quantum Mechanics, where it was considered foundational for the theory of atomic spectra. Nowadays, we know that its original formulation in terms of quantum numbers describing one-particle states is not general enough, and the antisymmetry of the fermionic wavefunction can be considered a principle in some formulations of quantum mechanics (although it becomes a theorem, the spin-statistics theorem, in QFT).

The definition in terms of quantum numbers is exactly equivalent to the definition in terms of antisymmetry of the Fermionic wave function (just choose a discrete basis for the wave function, and then the labels of that discrete basis become quantum numbers)

@Travis The original formulation referred to the one particle approximation, and the quantum numbers were those selecting one-particle states.  I'll make this point clearer in my answer.

There's a myth among those outside of academia that scientists have perfectly circumscribed definitions for things like principle, law, hypothesis, theory, etc.  The truth is that aesthetics plays the largest role in how things are named.
